# How to iterate a function in multiple excel sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The function below works fine when I run it in a single data set but it doesn't work in multiple data sets.
I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong with the iteration.

**ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis**

Any help will be appreciated.

```
 def transform(df):

    df['dtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtime'])
    print('The index is:',df.index)
    #find the interval by substracting the second date from the first one
    a = df.loc[0, 'dtime']
    b = df.loc[1, 'dtime']
    c = a - b
    minutes = c.total_seconds() / 60
    d=int(minutes) #d can be only 15 ,30 or 60
    df.set_index('dtime',inplace=True,drop=False)
    #This function will create new row to the time series anytime when it finds  gaps and will fill it with NaN or leave it blank.
    #df.drop_duplicates(keep='first') keeps the first value of duplicates
    if d==15:
        df= df.set_index('dtime',inplace=True).asfreq('-15T') 
        df.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
    elif d==30: 
        #df.KW.resample('-30T').sum()
        df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-30T')
        #df=df.asfreq('-30T')
        #df.reset_index(drop=True)
        #df.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
        #df=df.reset_index(drop=True) 
    elif d==60:
        df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-60T')
        df.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
    else:
        pass
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
xls=pd.ExcelFile('example1.xlsx') 

name_dict = {}

snames = xls.sheet_names

for sn in snames:
    name_dict[sn] = xls.parse(sn)

for key, value in name_dict.items():
    print('Num missing values:',value['KW'].isnull().sum())
    transform(value)
```

This is the error.

```
Num missing values: 1
The index is: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15985, step=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5f9677c4de77> in <module>
     12 for key, value in name_dict.items():
     13     print('Num missing values:',value['KW'].isnull().sum())
---> 14     transform(value)

<ipython-input-1-042f5dd9b3a2> in transform(df)
     17     elif d==30:
     18         #df.KW.resample('-30T').sum()
---> 19         df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-30T')
     20         #df=df.asfreq('-30T')
     21         #df.reset_index(drop=True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in asfreq(self, freq, method, how, normalize, fill_value)
   6762         from pandas.core.resample import asfreq
   6763         return asfreq(self, freq, method=method, how=how, normalize=normalize,
-> 6764                       fill_value=fill_value)
   6765 
   6766     def at_time(self, time, asof=False):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in asfreq(obj, freq, method, how, normalize, fill_value)
   1589         dti = date_range(obj.index[0], obj.index[-1], freq=freq)
   1590         dti.name = obj.index.name
-> 1591         new_obj = obj.reindex(dti, method=method, fill_value=fill_value)
   1592         if normalize:
   1593             new_obj.index = new_obj.index.normalize()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    185         @wraps(func)
    186         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 187             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    188 
    189         if not PY2:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3564         kwargs.pop('axis', None)
   3565         kwargs.pop('labels', None)
-> 3566         return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(**kwargs)
   3567 
   3568     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex_axis'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3687         # perform the reindex on the axes
   3688         return self._reindex_axes(axes, level, limit, tolerance, method,
-> 3689                                   fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
   3690 
   3691     def _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   3499         if index is not None:
   3500             frame = frame._reindex_index(index, method, copy, level,
-> 3501                                          fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   3502 
   3503         return frame

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _reindex_index(self, new_index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   3510         return self._reindex_with_indexers({0: [new_index, indexer]},
   3511                                            copy=copy, fill_value=fill_value,
-> 3512                                            allow_dups=False)
   3513 
   3514     def _reindex_columns(self, new_columns, method, copy, level,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _reindex_with_indexers(self, reindexers, fill_value, copy, allow_dups)
   3808                                                 fill_value=fill_value,
   3809                                                 allow_dups=allow_dups,
-> 3810                                                 copy=copy)
   3811 
   3812         if copy and new_data is self._data:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in reindex_indexer(self, new_axis, indexer, axis, fill_value, allow_dups, copy)
   4412         # some axes don't allow reindexing with dups
   4413         if not allow_dups:
-> 4414             self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
   4415 
   4416         if axis >= self.ndim:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _can_reindex(self, indexer)
   3574         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3575         if not self.is_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3576             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3577 
   3578     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None,
```

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

[Dataset in excel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2we0gh1xgo0gzvs/example1.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this problem is occurring specifically because you're trying to scan multiple sheets in a document. I think the problem is with the data itself, and the error could have just as easily occurred in your single data set.

Looking at your Excel file, I think the problem is that both sheets have two rows with the datetime `8/27/2019  10:30:00 PM`. I think `df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-30T')` only works if the dtime column contains no duplicates. Try removing duplicates beforehand, either by manually editing the data or by dropping duplicates from the dataframe.

```
elif d==30: 
    df= df.drop_duplicates("dtime")
    df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-30T')
```